# Reloading Webview from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, android-webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to reload my Webview which in in my MainActivity from FirebaseMessagingService when ever a notification arrive and I tap on the notification.

Here is my code so far.

**FirebaseMessagingService.java** in **onMessageReceived** method I have

```
if(MainActivity.isAppRunning){
 Delegate.theMainActivity.onNotificationRefresh();
 }
```

**Delegate.java**

```
package ###@@##@@;

public class Delegate {
    static MainActivity theMainActivity;
}
```

And in my **MainActivity** there is this method which i am trying to call

```
public void onNotificationRefresh() {
        webView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
}
```

right now when every i recieve notification instead of calling reload app crashes.

**Error Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
    Process: ###@@##@@, PID: 11092
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'pool-3-thread-1'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {e88a3d1} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {e88a3d1})
        at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2588)
        at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:1005)
        at com.###@@##@@.MainActivity.onNotificationRefresh(MainActivity.java:293)
        at com.###@@##@@.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:88)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: `calling reload app crashes.`  You need to share that crash log with question

Comment: ok wait let me.

Comment: please check my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way you can use **`BroadcastReceiver`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.e("NOTIFICATION_DATA", remoteMessage.getData() + "");

        Intent new_intent = new Intent();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();// use bundle if you want to pass data
        bundle.putString("msgBody", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        new_intent.putExtra("msg", bundle);

        new_intent.setAction("ACTION_ACTIVITY");
        sendBroadcast(new_intent);      


    }
}
```

Than Use in your activity like this

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // registering BroadcastReceiver
        if (activityReceiver != null) {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("ACTION_ACTIVITY");
            registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(activityReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // reload your webview here
            webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod?tab=profile");
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Great its worked. but i need to reload it when tapping on notification not automatically. is that possible??

Comment: @WaqasArshad yes that is possible but you need to create notification for that and also need to handle notification click event when user click on that notification your activity will open

Comment: can you share any example link here so i can get some help from it. Thanks