# Implementing Broadcast reciever for a particular activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am building an android app, which is meant for giving feedback for a set of questions.The no of questions vary each time depending on the server data.In the code below I have the implementation of the submit button in my QuestionAnswerActivity which saves data both online and offline. I want to implement a BroadcastReceiver which should detect the network changes in the QuestionAnswerActivity and submit the data(answers) stored in the local database(offline).It should also show appropriate toast messages.for ex:"No internet connection" or "Internet connected".

Comment: Welcome to `stackoverflow` have a look **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761531/7666442 you will get hint how to use Broadcast reciever

Comment: @NileshRathod   Sure sir.Will improve from next time.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Register a broadcast in manifest and use the code below.

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Cursor cursor;
SQLHelper helper;
Boolean IsSubmitted=false;
Context c;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    helper = new SQLHelper(context);
    this.c = context;
    pt = new ProcessTask();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
            Log.d("Network", "Internet YAY");

            // Code when internet is connected 

            cursor = helper.getProcessTask(context);
            getdataFromSql(cursor,context);

        } else if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.d("Network", "No internet :(");


        }
    }
}
```

in Manifest add

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NetworkReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: How to implement it for a particular activity(In my case for QuestionAnswerActivity).

Comment: @AmruthaDesai check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761347/reloading-webview-from-firebasemessagingservice/51761531#51761531

Comment: Amrutha Desai, In question answer activity, check for network connection on submit button. if there is no coverage of internet store it in sql, and then flash your sql data to server in the OnRecieve method in the above broadcast.